# How can I code a javascript function that will add a period to the end of a string every five seconds?

Tags: javascript

I am using the following code:

```
<div class="loading-mask" id="loading-mask" style="display: none;">
    <span>Authenticating</span>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        document.getElementsByClassName('form')[0]
            .addEventListener("submit", function () {  
                document.getElementById("loading-mask").style.display = "block";
            }, false);
    })();
</script>
```

What this does is to make a Div called loading-mask visible after a user clicks submit. How can I make it so that it also displays a period after the word "Authenticating" with more periods being added at the rate of one every five seconds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `setInterval` function. More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval

```
setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById('loading-mask').innerHTML += '.';
}, 5000);
```

Comment: But will this repeatedly add new periods or does it just happen once?

Comment: This will add new periods every 5 seconds. If you want to stop it, you can assign its return to a variable and then call `clearInterval` passing it as a parameter.